# Scala Play Framework Build in Validation

Tags: scala, playframework

I used the build in validation in play framework to validate the name using validation.match, but it throws an **"identifier expected but 'match' found"**

```
package controllers    
import play.*
import play.mvc.*
import play.data.validation.Validation

object Application extends Controller {    

    def adduser = {
        val name = params.get("name")
        validation.match(name, "[A-Za-z ]+").message("Please enter valid name")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you intend to use the "matches" function that the String type provides. 'match' itself is a reserved word, which is why the compiler is complaining.